# Suck on "checking if fork works with pthread..." when installing ruby 2.5.7 on linux by using rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am now follow the following tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-22-04) to install ruby 2.5.7 by rbenv. When I user the following command `rbenv install 2.5.7 -v`. It keep suck on `checking if fork works with pthread...` How can I solve it?

I am using orbstack on mac m2 and the version of linux in orbstack is 22.04 TLS

Comment: Do you really want to use a ruby version which have not been supported for years? Can you at least try to install a current ruby version? Even on version 2.5 there is a patch 2.5.9.

Comment: ya, because my company is using 2.5.7 for development...